# What are the requirements to skip promotion games/Divisions?

Tags: league-of-legends

I understand that in order to skip promotion games and divisions, you must be playing consistently at a higher level than your division suggests but, how high above your current league do you have to be playing in order to skip promos or a division?

Comment: Are you sure you really talk about skipping promotion games ? and not about skipping divisions after your promotion games ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to have an MMR that is at least **1 Tier** higher than your current division.

For example if you are silver 5 but you have the hidden Elo of a Gold 4 Player you will be instantly promoted to the next division once you reach 100 LP. You can also skip divisions and promotions at the same time but this is very rare (skipping promotions is really rare already).

Comment: I did it twice while I was in gold league, lol.

Comment: @Fabián skipping divisions or promotions ;)? Skipping divisions is pretty common, skipping promotions is rather rare.

Comment: Gold 5, waited almost 26 days, finished promo -- > gold 3... then got a winning streak, got in a promo: won, lost, won --> gold 1.

Comment: Oh well, at least it happened to me when I was using Kayle mid pre-nerf.

Comment: @Fabián You skipped a division, which is fairly common.  The answer is about skipping the promo games, which is far rarer.

Comment: @AaronDufour yes I find that pretty rare as well.

Answer (score 0):

I only had to win 1 game from my promo, but 2days ago i was on a winning streak of 15 out of 17games played, 1day before i was in a big winning streak also.
But it was on my smurf account that was in silver